# Derivative in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Can someone please explain where this comes from? My textbook only says that is a derivative in spherical coordinates. (**r** is a position vector and $U$ is the potential energy).

$-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \textbf{r}} = -\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial R}\textbf{e}_R+\dfrac{1}{R}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\textbf{e}_{\theta}+\dfrac{1}{R\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \varphi}\textbf{e}_{\varphi}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

This is the gradient operator in spherical coordinates. See: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). Look under the heading "Del formulae." This page demonstrates the complexity of these type of formulae in general. You can derive these with careful manipulation of partial derivatives too if you know what you're doing.

The other option is to learn some (basic) Differential Geometry. You can take a course or read a book on it if you really care. Depending on your field of interest, you may not need to care about HOW to get this.

Comment: You don't need differential geometry to derive these expressions. When you study physics, you learn vector calculus in curvilinear coordinate systems before you hear the term "differential geometry" for the first time. It's just a matter of manipulating partial derivatives.

Comment: @joriki OK, I guess it depends on your background and what you call "differential geometry" I felt that as a physics student they spent a lot of time teaching us DG in physics, etc.

Comment: @joriki From my perspective it is a lot EASIER to derive such formulae with the machinery of DG to bear on the problem. Harder from just using partial derivatives. But YMMV.

Comment: I agree that it makes things easier and gives you a better perspective on what you're doing. I just wanted to prevent the OP from being deterred, because if you look up differential geometry (e.g. in the Wikipedia article) it's mostly about advanced stuff that $~95\%$ of the people who need gradient operators in curvilinear coordinates in their daily work will never get to. To me it seems a bit like saying that counting is done using generating functions -- it can be much easier, and you get a more systematic perspective, but you can also count without ever hearing about generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: first, the LHR $U$ and the RHS $U$ are **different** functions. The first (I will call it $V$) is the potential energy in cartesian coordinates, the second is the potential energy in spherical coordinates. They are related by
$$V(x(R,\theta,\varphi),y(R,\theta,\varphi),z(R,\theta,\varphi)) = U(R,\theta,\varphi).$$
$$V(x,y,z) = U(R(x,y,z),\theta(x,y,z),\varphi(x,y,z)).$$
You can find the relation between the partial derivatives of $U$ and $V$ using the chain rule.

Now,
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial\mathbf r} =
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}{\mathbf i} +
\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}{\mathbf j} +
\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}{\mathbf k} =
\frac{\partial V}{\partial\mathbf r} =
(\cdots){\mathbf i} +
(\cdots){\mathbf j} +
(\cdots){\mathbf k}
$$
(where the $(\cdots)$ are the partial derivatives of $V$ expressed using the partial derivatives of $U$.

Last step: write ${\mathbf i}, {\mathbf j}, {\mathbf k}$ in the new base ${\mathbf e}_R,{\mathbf e}_\theta,{\mathbf e}_\varphi$.